# React & Formik, Passing data between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, formik

I am a beginner in React. I'm trying to create my first ToDo App.
Currently, I have two components - one with input and submit button (to enter data) - created with formik, second - simply component where I want to display this data.
I'm not sure how to pass data between these components and I'm looking for tips on how to do it correctly.

Here is my code:

First component( to enter data):

```js
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

function MyForm(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ task: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
          <>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={handleChange("task")}
              placeholder="Write a task"
            />

            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Click" />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

Second component( to display data):

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import MyForm from "./MyForm";

const TaskContainer = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Here is your list:</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TaskContainer;
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Ho4.png) is simple example of what I want to display in second component:

I will be grateful for any advice

Comment: Also check Redux or MobX. There are used to control state of your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is creating the statement of your task in the `Parent component`. After that use the `callback function` (pass it through props) to change its values (I use **useCallback** hook to prevent useless re-rendering of child components):

**Parent component**

```js
import React from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = React.useState([]);

  const addTask = React.useCallback(
    (newTask) => {
      setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
    },
    [tasks]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <MyForm tasks={tasks} addTask={addTask} />
      <TaskContainer tasks={tasks} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Form component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

function MyForm({ tasks, setTasks }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ task: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values) => setTasks(values)}>
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
          <>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={handleChange('task')}
              placeholder="Write a task"
            />

            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Click" />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

**Tasks component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MyForm from './MyForm';

const TaskContainer = ({ tasks, setTasks }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Here is your list:</Text>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Text>{task}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default TaskContainer;
```